# Swiper slides as sections & navbar as pagination

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, swiper.js

I am using next, typescript, and [swiper](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api). I want the current slide/section to be highlighted in the navbar. I was able to achieve this using vanilla javascript https://codepen.io/ms9ntQfa/pen/eYrxLxV but have no idea how to do this in tsx.

This is my code so far

```
import type { NextPage } from 'next'
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/react";
import Head from 'next/head'
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css'
import "swiper/css";

import { Mousewheel } from "swiper";


const Home: NextPage = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Create Next App</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>

      <main className={styles.main}>
        <div className={styles.card}>
          <div className={styles.header}>
            <div className={styles.navbar}>
              <h2>Logo</h2>
              <ul className={styles.items}>
                <li>Home</li>
                <li>Foo</li>
                <li>Bar</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
          <Swiper
            direction={"horizontal"}
            slidesPerView={1}
            mousewheel={true}
            modules={[Mousewheel]}
            className={styles.swiper}
          >
            <SwiperSlide id="home">Home</SwiperSlide>
            <SwiperSlide id="foo">Foo</SwiperSlide>
            <SwiperSlide id="bar">Bar</SwiperSlide>
          </Swiper>
        </div>
      </main>
    </>
  )
}

export default Home
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is something you can change with your code:

- Extract the Navbar `<li>` to an array of string then map it out
- Create a state to track the active index
- Use `onActiveIndexChange` event of `swiperjs` to get current active slide

I also create a code sandbox, you can see it [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nextjs-j2yft6?file=pages/index.js)

Here is the code snippet:

```
import Head from 'next/head';
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css';
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide, useSwiper } from 'swiper/react';
import 'swiper/css';
import React from 'react';

import { Mousewheel } from 'swiper';

const NAV = ['Home', 'Foo', 'Bar'];

export default function Home() {
  const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = React.useState(0);
  const swiper = useSwiper();

  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Create Next App</title>
      </Head>

      <main>
        <div>
          <div>
            <div>
              <h2>Logo</h2>
              <ul>
                {NAV.map((item, index) => (
                  <li
                    key={index}
                    style={{
                      color: index === activeIndex ? 'crimson' : 'black',
                    }}
                  >
                    {item}
                  </li>
                ))}
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>

          <p>This is horizontal scroll</p>
          <Swiper
            direction={'horizontal'}
            slidesPerView={1}
            mousewheel={true}
            modules={[Mousewheel]}
            style={{
              background: 'gold',
            }}
            onActiveIndexChange={(swiper) => {
              setActiveIndex(swiper.activeIndex);
            }}
          >
            <SwiperSlide id="home">Home</SwiperSlide>
            <SwiperSlide id="foo">Foo</SwiperSlide>
            <SwiperSlide id="bar">Bar</SwiperSlide>
          </Swiper>
        </div>
      </main>
    </>
  );
}
```